# Contact Joining (Android M)

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-6.0-marshmallow

i try to join two Contacts, a default Contact from the Default Address-Store, and a Contact of my own Provider.
I have the following code-snippet of the com.android.Contact app:

```
private interface JoinContactQuery {
    String[] PROJECTION = {
        RawContacts._ID,
        RawContacts.CONTACT_ID,
        RawContacts.NAME_VERIFIED,
        RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_SOURCE,
    };

    String SELECTION = RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=? OR " + RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?";

    int _ID = 0;
    int CONTACT_ID = 1;
    int NAME_VERIFIED = 2;
    int DISPLAY_NAME_SOURCE = 3;
}


Cursor c = resolver.query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            JoinContactQuery.PROJECTION,
            JoinContactQuery.SELECTION,
        new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId1), String.valueOf(contactId2)}, null);

if (c == null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to open Contacts DB cursor");
    return;
}

long rawContactIds[];
long verifiedNameRawContactId = -1;
try {
    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
    return;
    }
    int maxDisplayNameSource = -1;
    rawContactIds = new long[c.getCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < rawContactIds.length; i++) {
    c.moveToPosition(i);
    long rawContactId = c.getLong(JoinContactQuery._ID);
    rawContactIds[i] = rawContactId;
    int nameSource = c.getInt(JoinContactQuery.DISPLAY_NAME_SOURCE);
    if (nameSource > maxDisplayNameSource) {
        maxDisplayNameSource = nameSource;
    }
    }

    // Find an appropriate display name for the joined contact:
    // if should have a higher DisplayNameSource or be the name
    // of the original contact that we are joining with another.
    if (writable) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rawContactIds.length; i++) {
        c.moveToPosition(i);
        if (c.getLong(JoinContactQuery.CONTACT_ID) == contactId1) {
            int nameSource = c.getInt(JoinContactQuery.DISPLAY_NAME_SOURCE);
            if (nameSource == maxDisplayNameSource
                    && (verifiedNameRawContactId == -1
                            || c.getInt(JoinContactQuery.NAME_VERIFIED) != 0)) {
                verifiedNameRawContactId = c.getLong(JoinContactQuery._ID);
            }
        }
    }
    }
} finally {
    c.close();
}

// For each pair of raw contacts, insert an aggregation exception
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
for (int i = 0; i < rawContactIds.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rawContactIds.length; j++) {
    if (i != j) {
        buildJoinContactDiff(operations, rawContactIds[i], rawContactIds[j]);
    }
    }
}

// Mark the original contact as "name verified" to make sure that the contact
// display name does not change as a result of the join
if (verifiedNameRawContactId != -1) {
    Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(
        ContentUris.withAppendedId(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, verifiedNameRawContactId));
    builder.withValue("name_verified", 1);
    operations.add(builder.build());
}
```

My Problem: The "name_verified" Field is removed on Android M (Preview 2). Whats the "correct" way to join two Contacts (and do not change the Name of the Contact)?

*** EDIT / Solution ***

Remove name_verified and set "IS_SUPER_PRIMARY" to content uri

```
    //mark as SUPER PRIMARY
    if (verifiedNameRawContactId != -1) {
        operations.add(
                ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, verifiedNameRawContactId))
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1)
                        .build());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not quite clear to me but i think your are trying to join two contacts and one name is taking precedence over another but not the way you want it.

The correct way to join contacts is to add a row in this table and keep the type as TYPE_KEEP_TOGETHER. [AggregationsExceptions table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.html)

If you want to keep the name of the first raw_contact mark the name record of the contact in Data table (StructuredName) as IS_SUPER_PRIMARY

[IS_SUPER_PRIMARY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#IS_SUPER_PRIMARY)